# How to configure eslint for particular ECMA features?

Tags: eslint

- The project targets specific version of Node.js. This is the runtime of the code.
- There is no transpilation step. JavaScript code is deployed as it is.
- Particular Node version can support particular ECMA version partly. I want to use those features that are supported.
- Eslint allows for specifying compatibility as ECMA version only, as far as I know.

**How can I tell Eslint that a particular ECMA feature is supported?**

For example: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#node16_9. Node v16.9 supports ES2022 only partly, so I cannot set `ecmaVersion` to `2022`. But I want to use `instance class fields`, for example, which is supported by Node v16.9.

I know about https://github.com/mysticatea/eslint-plugin-node and its fork https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-n, which are supposed to somehow configure Eslint based on the `package.engines.node` value. But my question is about the core Eslint - is there a way of configuring particular ECMA features that are supported by the runtime?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to override `parserOptions.ecmaVersion` with additional features, except for `jsx`, `globalReturn`, and `impliedStrict` ([see the source](https://github.com/eslint/espree/blob/main/lib/features.js#L17)). If there's a relatively short list of features you'd like to additionally allow, you could manually disable and enable rules, but eslint-plugin-n seems like a much less brittle solution.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I've tried `eslint-plugin-n` but faced few issues, which I've filed in their repo. But in the context of this question I'd like to figure out how to enable/disable rules to "cherry-pick" a particular feature beyond, say, ES2021. Searching for "instance class fields" in https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/ didn't give me any result. Can you please suggest which rules to enable/disable to allow this particular feature, for example? So that I understand the logic.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not about rules but about parser… Yet I don't know eslint that much to be sure about this.